# How to make elements blink in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom function in jQuery which makes an element blink when it is clicked. What is the proper way to do this in Vue?

I assume it is done with a directive? Is there a way to make it so I can add "blinkable" to any element to make it blink when clicked?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.fn.blink = function () {
 var button = this;
 var theinterval = setInterval(function(){
  button.toggleClass("blink");
 }, 20);
 setTimeout(function(){
  clearInterval(theinterval);
  button.removeClass("blink");
 }, 400);
};

$("document").ready(function () {

  $("div.blinkable").click(function () {

    $(this).blink();

  });
  
});
</script>

<style>
div.button {
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  padding:5px;
}

div.blink {
  background:red;
}
</style>

<div class="button blinkable">button 1</div>
<div class="button blinkable">button 2</div>
<div class="button blinkable">button 3</div>
<div class="button blinkable">button 4</div>
```

Comment: A directive would be one approach. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yea but Im not sure what the proper way is to do it. The only way I can think of seems like a hack.

Answer (score 5):

I'd just go with pure CSS animation

```css
div.button {
  background:purple;
  color:white;
  margin-bottom:2px;
  padding:5px;
}

div.button:active {
  animation: blink 0.02s 20 alternate;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from { background-color: purple; }
  to { background-color: red; }
}
```

```html
<div class="button blinkable">button 1</div>
<div class="button blinkable">button 2</div>
<div class="button blinkable">button 3</div>
<div class="button blinkable">button 4</div>
```

Comment: problem is it only blinks while :active. I want it to blink for like a whole second.

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it with a method and some vanilla JS: https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/QgJZEP

```
methods: {
    blink(event) {

  event.target.style.background = 'red'
  setTimeout(()=>{
    event.target.style.background = 'purple'
  },500)

    }
```